# Java 8 Map to a List of Objects with one field grouped into a List

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, pojo

Newbie question. I have an original bean coming from the DB row-by-row as

```
public class DataBean {
   private Integer employeeId;
   private String org;
   private String comments;
   // + Constructors, getters/setters
}
```

I need to map it to a different bean with multiple Org's grouped by Employee ID into a List. **Only Orgs can be multiple for an EmployeeID; the Comments field is guaranteed to be the same.**

```
public class CustomDataBean {
   private Integer employeeId;
   private List<String> orgs;
   private String comments;
   // + Constructors, getters/setters
}
```

Struggling to get started. Was thinking of `groupingBy` such as the below but that returns a Map, and I'm not building a sub-List.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> temp = origData.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(OrigBean::getEmployeeId,
    /* 2nd param? */ .. ))
```

My goal is a transformed `List<CustomDataBean>`.

Comment: Just to make sure I understood right: Your input is a `List` of `DataBean`, and you want to group the `DataBean`s that have the same `employeeId` into `CustomDataBean`s ?

Comment: Try with adapter design pattern.

Comment: An Employee can have different Orgs. I'm getting row-by-row results, and need to create a bean where an Employee has a List<String> for the orgs he belongs to. In other words, all the Orgs for that Employee wrapped into a List field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just can use this:

```
List<CustomDataBean> result = origData.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DataBean::getEmployeeId))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new CustomDataBean(
                e.getKey(),
                e.getValue().stream().map(DataBean::getOrg).collect(Collectors.toList()),
                e.getValue().get(0).getComments()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This maps the grouped results to your `CustomDataBean` object.

For the input:

```
List<DataBean> origData = Arrays.asList(
        new DataBean(1, "a", "c"),
        new DataBean(1, "b", "c"),
        new DataBean(1, "c", "c"),
        new DataBean(2, "a", "d"),
        new DataBean(2, "c", "d")
);
```

The result will be this:

```
CustomDataBean[employeeId=1, orgs=[a, b, c], comments='c']
CustomDataBean[employeeId=2, orgs=[a, c], comments='d']
```

Comment: Working, thanks - and really straightforward. I didn't realize a 1-param `groupingBy` would give a `Map<String,DataBean>` (and from then on it was simple).

Comment: `Collectors.groupingBy(DataBean::getEmployeeId)` is the same like `Collectors.groupingBy(DataBean::getEmployeeId, Collectors.toList())`. The `toList()` collector is used by default.

Answer (score 3):

To answer both the questions, use `Collectors.mapping` as the downstream as :

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> temp = origData.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(DataBean::getEmployeeId,
                Collectors.mapping(DataBean::getOrg, Collectors.toList())));
```

and further, achieve your goal to obtain a `List<CustomDataBean>` as:

```
List<CustomDataBean> goal = origData.stream()
        .map(a -> new CustomDataBean(a.getEmployeeId(), temp.get(a.employeeId), a.getComments()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```